# Подскажите почему не работает данный код?

Tags: php, ajax, curl

```js
    require "../db.php";       

    $urlApi = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx/api';
    $token = 'mytoken';

    // Забираем пользователя и изменяем его id, чтобы нельзя было обратится за другого
    $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
    $var = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);
    
    $data = array(); 

    $arOptions = [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'x-inclo-token:' . $token,
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ],
    ];

    if (isset($_POST)){ 
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ // Разбираем массив $_POST
            if ($key == 'url_api'){
                $urlApi = $urlApi . $value;
                $arOptions['CURLOPT_URL'] = $urlApi;
            }
            if ($key == 'type'){ 
                if ($value == 'post'){
                    $arOptions['CURLOPT_POST'] = true;
                        $MyFlag = 1;
                }else if($value == 'get'){ 
                    $arOptions['CURLOPT_GET'] = true;
                    $MyFlag = 0;
                }
            }
            $data[$key] = $value;
            // $a[$key]=$value; 
        }
        $data['id'] = $var->id;
    }    
    if ($MyFlag == 1){
        $arOptions['CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS'] = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $arOptions);
    // $res = curl_exec($ch);
    // curl_close($ch);  
    // $res = json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    // echo ($res);
```

Деббагинг, показал что ошибка в строке:
`curl_setopt_array($ch, $arOptions);`

Вызывая его вот так:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "./Scripts/Interaction_Api.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'dataString',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            type: 'post',
            url_api: '/set',
            setname: array[0],
            clo: array[1],
            geo: ['ru'],
            trafficsource: array[3],
            paranoia: true,
            streamlink: array[5],
        },success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: А ошибку нам, судя по всему, надо угадать, да?

Comment: @u_mulder Прикол в том, что я вызываю его, и просто смотрю ответ сервера, там естественно 500, а при запуске напрямую, он ничего не выдаёт

Comment: @u_mulder Просто думал, ошибка супер банальная и чего-то не вызвал, она определённо логическая, валидатор не выдает ошибок

Comment: curl_error что выдает?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в ответе рабочий код, спасибо за попытку помочь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ошибку, ошибка в том, что я неправильно добавляю элементы к $arOptions, в итоге я полностью решил отказаться от этого и просто напрямую задаю что-то к CUrl запросу, итоговый рабочий код:

```js
<?php 
    require "../db.php";       

    $urlApi = 'http://my_ip/api';
    $token = 'mytoken';

    // Забираем пользователя и изменяем его id, чтобы нельзя было обратится за другого
    $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
    $var = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);
    
    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array(); 

    $arOptions = [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'x-inclo-token:' . $token,
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ],
    ];

    if (isset($_POST)){ 
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ // Разбираем массив $_POST
            if ($key == 'url_api'){
                $urlApi = $urlApi . $value;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlApi);
            }
            if ($key == 'type'){ 
                if ($value == 'post'){
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    $MyFlag = 1;
                }else if($value == 'get'){ 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
                    $MyFlag = 0;
                }
            }
            $data[$key] = $value;
            // $a[$key]=$value; 
        }
        $data['id'] = $var->id;
    }    
    if ($MyFlag == 1){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $arOptions);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);     
    $res = json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo ($res);
?>
```

Был бы очень благодарен, за Ваши идеи по оптимизации кода